# Assert ActiveRecord method is called through class method with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I'm stumped on what appears to be a fairly simple thing I'd like to do. I've got a pretty simple class:

```rb
class User
  def self.find_by_search(query)
    query = query.to_s.strip

    if query.upcase.start_with?("USER")
      find(query)
    else
      find_by(name: "*#{query}*")
    end
  end
end
```

I'd love to test that logic, so I simply need to assert that either `find` or `find_by` is called with the expected parameter. I've tried a couple of things:

```rb
User.find_by_search("USER0000")
expect(ActiveRecord::Base).to receive(:find)
```

and

```rb
User.find_by_search("USER0000")
expect(User).to receive(:find) # didn't really think this would work, but figured I'd try anyway
```

Both result in

```
expected: 1 time with any arguments
received: 0 times with any arguments
```

I must be doing something dumb here, but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: The keys were decided long before me, so I just have to deal with them. They're strange, but they work for us, more or less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expect().to receive()` should be define before we execute the operation.

```
expect(User).to receive(:find) 
User.find_by_search("USER0000")
```

Read more about [expect(...).to receive(...)](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/expecting-messages)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the clarification! I knew I was doing something dumb, lol